# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant' in anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have anaconda and `python 3.5`. I've installed tensorflow and other libraries (numpy, pandas ,matplotlib). whenever I run an example tensorflow program I found on the internet, I run into an error when declaring a variable with 
`tf.constant()`

I've tried various solutions provided from other questions most commonly files names called `tensorflow.py` being the program name but my program is called `example.py`

I've tried reinstalling anaconda , making new conda environments with specific versions of python and I tried tensorflow 2.0 beta

```
import tensorflow as tf 
X = tf.constant( train_features , dtype=tf.float32 )
```

I expected the program to run as it was an example but the error is

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant'
```

Comment: is your folder name tensorflow,have you tried removing completely and installing again

Comment: the path to example.py dosent include tensorflow in any of the names

Comment: Did you ran this code in Anaconda Environment? If yes, were you able to import tensorflow? Can you try running the code in the local (not env)? Can you copy full trace of the error? Thanks! This is strange. I tried with Anaconda with Spyder. created an example.py in a "tensorflow" folder on Desktop. I could run the code without any issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observation is correct. It may be because `Tensorflow Version 2.0` might not be compatible with `Python Version 3.5`.

You can create a Virtual Environment in Anaconda with `Python Version 3.6` (or `3.7`) and it will execute successfully.

After Creating the Virtual Environment, execute the below Code, after activating the respective Virtual Environment:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.0 #If run in Jupyter Notebook
import tensorflow as tf
X = tf.constant( 100 , dtype=tf.float32 )
```

Comment: Hey @Tensorflow Support, What do you mean by might not be? Either it is or it is not. I tried system wide installation with `Python3.6.9` and it didn't work.

`python3.6 -m pip install tensorflow-cpu==2.2.0` didn't work

`python3.6 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0` didn't work.

Comment: @Sowmya, What is the error that you are facing. Can you try replacing `python3.6` with `python3` and see how it goes.

Comment: I was not sure of what was breaking but I did `pip freeze` and removed each every old and new version of tensorflow. Then, finally installed just one version of tensorflow (`2.2.0`) with `python3 -m pip install tensorflow`. It is working fine. However, there are some amazing people who write `tf.constants()` when displaying and distributing their code in public and it creates a hell lot of trouble for others. For e.g. here

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Fabes201/a088bf6aceeace04da5d5b438d85bd2c/raw/aadd4a83f48b1b3868be22eb157de5f545163e64/eager_exec.py